# Django: foreign key access through related objects

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, models

Suppose I have a model `Profile` that relates to the standard `User` model through either a `ForeignKey` with `unique=True` relationship, or a OneToOne relationship:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = (either a ForeignKey/OneToOne relationship)
    ...
```

If I have understood the documentation, the database representation of the column will be `user_id`, from Django automatically adding `_id`. This user_id will contain a series of integers.

Suppose again I instantiate an object of this model in the shell, and try and access the  `user` attribute:

```
a_profile = Profile()

a_profile.user
```

From what I have read, in the case of a 'ForeignKey' relationship, the `user` attribute should now be a descriptor, and accessing it will invoke it's __ get __ method, giving me access to the related model instance - in this case the User instance.

MY QUESTION:

I have noticed that I can access the Profile instance through the User instance as well, with a `OneToOne` relationship, through:

```
user_profile = User.objects.all()[0]
user_profile.profile
```

When I do the same thing but have a `ForeignKey` relationship, I get a query set.

What is happening behind the scenes? And is the `user` attribute on a `Profile` instance with a `OneToOne` relationship also a descriptor working the same way as in the case of a `ForeignKey` relationship?

Thank you!

Comment: Django creates it automatically backreference. You can read something about it here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

Answer (score 0):

You can only use Object_X.user if the relationship between them is one to one:

[Check this.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/)